# Why did Hashem choose to give the message about Resurrection through Gavriel?

Tags: malach-angel, resurrection-of-the-dead, daniel-book-of

Shalom.

I am having difficulty understanding why Hashem chose to deliver the definitive message about something as important as the Resurrection through an angel and not, directly, Himself (Daniel 12:2). I understand a messenger can be faithful, but why was it necessary to interpose a mediator in this (massively important) case?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: See the Maharal of Prague's introductions to Gevuroth Hashem where he explains that the world to come is not mentioned explicitly by the prophets due to the inherent differences between inferential wisdom and experiential prophecy.

Comment: According to this page https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D there are a variety of sources so if one comes through an intermediary, then that's among a mix of other sources.

Comment: @Loewian - thanks, I will check that out :)

Comment: @rosends - apologies, I do not read Hebrew at all well - is there an English version of this page?

Comment: @TomW I don't have it in English but what it does is present other sources for the idea of resurrection from other biblical texts (such as in https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.26.19?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en )

Comment: @rosends - ok, thanks, I’ll check out the second link then. Blessings